# Reading and writing existing KML files using simplekml python module?

Tags: python, kml, simplekml

I am trying to add an image icon overlay into an existing KML file (that contains polygon layer from shapefile) without having to overwrite the file. I am currently using the "simplekml" python module which is giving me what I want.

The following code:

```
import simplekml

kml = simplekml.Kml()
screen = kml.newscreenoverlay(name='ScreenOverlay')
screen.icon.href='http://simplekml.googlecode.com/hg/samples/resources/simplekml-logo.png'
screen.overlayxy = simplekml.OverlayXY(x=0,y=1,xunits=simplekml.Units.fraction,
                                       yunits=simplekml.Units.fraction)
screen.screenxy = simplekml.ScreenXY(x=15,y=15,xunits=simplekml.Units.pixel,
                                     yunits=simplekml.Units.insetpixels)
screen.size.x = -1
screen.size.y = -1
screen.size.xunits = simplekml.Units.fraction
screen.size.yunits = simplekml.Units.fraction
kml.save("ScreenOverlay.kml")
```

Is there a way I can read and write an existing KML file without having to recreate a new one. Is there a function that allows me to modify and save the KML file?

Answer (score 4):

According to the creator of [simplekml](http://simplekml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html):

> Unfortunately, simplekml is just a kml generator, it cannot read and manipulate existing kml, only create it. You will have to use an alternative, such as [pyKML](http://pythonhosted.org/pykml/).

Source: [groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/simplekml](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/simplekml/OwHQinY6GZo)